# how to instanciate a generic collection array?

Tags: java, arrays, list, generics

Why this code comes out an error?

```
List<String>[] l = new ArrayList<String>[10];
```

Eclipse said I cannot create a generic array, but in fact I am  trying to create a collection array.

Comment: If you're looking to make an ArrayList of Strings, you might want to do this ArrayList<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [language spec, section 15.10](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10):

> "An array creation expression creates an object that is a new array whose elements are of the type specified by the PrimitiveType or ClassOrInterfaceType. It is a compile-time error if the ClassOrInterfaceType does not denote a reifiable type."

And per the [language spec, section 4.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.7):

> Because some type information is erased during compilation, not all types are available at run time. Types that are completely available at run-time are known as reifiable types.
>
> A type is reifiable if and only if one of the following holds:
>
> - It refers to a non-generic class or interface type declaration.
>
> ...

So put simply, "because the language says you can't". I understand the ultimate cause dealt with maintaining backward compatibility, but I'm not familiar with the details.

Answer (score 2):

It has naught to do with collections. The (raw) array constructor cannot take a parameterised type.

Try

```
List[] l = new ArrayList[10];
```

(Thanks @newacct)

Comment: The array of parameterized type is a valid *type* (e.g. `List<String>[]`). You just can't have parameterized component type in the *array creation* expression.

Answer (score 1):

Please try like this

```
List<String>[] al = new ArrayList[10];
al[0] = new ArrayList<String>();
al[1] = new ArrayList<Date>(); // Give u error because List accepts only String
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this : List[] l = new List[10];
Then add ArrayList(s) to your array of List...
The simple array cannot hold generics information. It was included in the language long before generics...